# Make a side bar to be on the right side of the screen

Tags: css, javascript, html

Hope this on topic.

I found [this skeleton](https://codepen.io/assemany/pen/grJoyx) and I'm trying to modify it to my needs.

1. How can I make the side bar to be on the right side instead of left side?
2. How can I make the buttons on the nav bar to be on the right side instead of the left?

In my county we write right-to-left.

Comment: like this ?https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LLjYPK
2 changes switch the order of `col-xs-12 col-sm-9` and side bar.
add `navbar-right` to ul  `<ul class="nav navbar-nav  navbar-right">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edited (sorry, forgot the second thing previously)

Add

```
#sidebar { float: right; }
```

and

```
.container-fluid > *:not(:first-of-type) {
  float: right;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EXvxxG